# How to inbuild a package to Nk.bin?

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I am developing windows CE 6.0 for VIA board. I have a MFC application as exe file. I want to include my application in the NK.bin image. how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your application to [one of the BIB files](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/17/platform-builder-using-bib-files-to-add-files-to-a.aspx) (e.g. PROJECT.BIB or PLATFORM.BIB).

Probably as simple as adding this (though if you have dependencies, you'll need them too):

```
FILES
MyApp.exe {dev pc path to your compiled app}\MyApp.exe     NK S
```

Comment: Thank you. one more thing, if i want to add my application to control panel,what i have to do?

Comment: @Eshwartamil you should post that as a new question.

Comment: Agreed.  That's a completely separate, and much more complicated question.